# Dynamic merged Background

Tags: java, android, colors, drawable

I have a jpeg "screen" and a number from 0 to 255.

The jpeg is partially transparent.

The number should be used to achieve a grayscale Drawable like it is used in this example to set the background:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(number, number, number));
```

Now, I want to programaticly merge these to values to get a single Image with the "number-Drawable" as Background and the jpeg overlaying it.
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) with a color drawable and a bitmap drawable as the layers. Please take care of supplying the transparency to the bitmap drawable as JPEG image format does not support transparency. Or use a PNG format for the "screen".